# What EL 2.2 implementation is available in Maven Central?

Tags: java, maven-2, el

I'm trying to find [Java EL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) 2.2 implementation available in Maven Central.

Answer (score 2):

One Possible one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Can be found in the java.net m2 repository: http://download.java.net/maven/2/

Comment: Yes, but as the official el-impl is not available on central .. any reason not to use the java.net m2 repository ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
            <artifactId>juel-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
            <artifactId>juel-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```